# Infile stops reading command line arguments

Tags: c++, command-line, ifstream

**Edit: As it turns out, it was a simple typo under the if(i==0) statement. I missed putting {} to enclose both first_nonterminal statements.

I'm creating a CFG for an assignment, but I've gotten stuck. My program is supposed to read a file (of strings) by getting the file name from the command line, and then do certain things with the contents of the file.

```
using namespace std;
string current, first_nonterminal;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
        if(argc != 2) 
        {
                std::cout << "No file name given" << std::endl; // if there is no file name in command line
                exit(1);
        }
    
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    if(!infile) 
    {
            std::cout << "Given file " << argv[1] << " will not open."; // if file refuses to open
            exit(2);
    }
    
    string word;
    for(int i = 0; infile >> word; ++i) 
    {
            cout << word << endl; // (debug) print input word
            try // check if first word is in correct format
            {
            if (i == 0 && word.find(':') == string::npos) // check only first word, 
            {
                    throw runtime_error("File does not have correct format.");
            }
            }
            catch(runtime_error &e)
            {
                    cout << "Error:" << e.what();
                    exit(3);
            }
            if (i==0)
                    first_nonterminal = word;
                    first_nonterminal.pop_back(); // remove colon
            insert(word); //put string through insert() method
    }

    randomize(); // randomize and replace 

    print(); // print end result

    infile.close();
}
```

The above code intakes a file which is formatted like so:

```
STMT: THIS THAT OTHER 
THIS: That carpet
THIS: Atlanta
THAT: is wild
OTHER: .
OTHER: , oooh OTHER2
OTHER2: oooh OTHER2
OTHER2: !
```

Any word that has a colon following it is considered a nonterminal, with the words following it considered terminals. Regardless, I've figured out the issue isn't my randomize() or insert() functions, as they work perfectly if I hard-code the file into the program. My issue is the file stops being read after a certain number of strings, and I'm not sure why. For example, when I put the above's file name into the command line, it runs through, but then after it puts "That" into the insert() function, it prints "carpet" via the debug cout, and then stops.

Comment: The two lines indented after `if (i==0)` are not both inside the if statement.  Did you intend the `first_nonterminal.pop_back(); // remove colon` to happen every time through the loop or only inside the `if (i==0)` if statement?  When I add braces so that it is inside, then it works for me: https://onlinegdb.com/HknkfHd4O   The reason this causes it to crash even though `first_nonterminal` is never used anywhere else is that `first_nonterminal` is never initialized to anything and then you `pop_back()` an uninitialized value.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That absolutely was the issue, I can't believe it was just the fact I made such a simple mistake. It does work now, thank you!

Comment: That's the thing about C and C++ - it doesn't warn you when you invoke undefined behaviour.  You are lucky it crashed instead of silently, subtly changing something else and giving you the wrong results.  Sometimes compilers have flags that can help track these things down - if you are using GCC for example try adding `-fsanitize=address,undefined` and hopefully that will catch some stuff.